# How can I download the third-party dependencies of spring-web.jar by maven?

Tags: spring, maven

The dependencies of Spring-web.jar do not contain third-party dependencies now. It only has other jar of spring framework. For example it depends on spring-core.jar. But the spring-web depends on some third-party jars. httpclient.jar is one of them. When I use maven to package my project that depends on spring-web, the httpclient.jar is not download automatically.
this is a segement of spring-web-5.2.15.RELEASE.pom.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I read the pom of spring-web in early version. I find that the denpendencies include httpclient.jar. But it is disappear in new version now. this is a segment of spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.pom.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

How can I download the dependencies?

Comment: Those are only optional dependencies so it won't be included ever. You will have to add them yourself. Why, you wouldn't want all the dependencies for which Spring has support into your own application now would you? Or would you like to get Apache HttpClient (3,4,5), OkHttp, but also Freemarker, Velocity, Thymeleaf etc. because they all have support for that (and many many many more). So Spring doesn't include those as those are application specific and it is you the application developer who knows what to include.

Comment: @M. Deinum: I update httpclient.jar from version 4 to version 5 because my project depends on it. My project depends on spring-web.jar too. This update broke the function of my project. Spring-web.jar depends on httpclient.jar 4. It can not run with httpclient 5 because the interface changed in verison 5, and the spring-web.jar can not find the method that it has used. Now I have to check the dependency of spring one by one manually . Is there some way to download the dependency of spring automatically now?

Comment: It will not download anything as it is an optional dependency, it never did download it without you as the developer specify it as a dependency. That has never been any different.

Comment: @M. Deinum:  OK. But now I have two httpclient in different version. Can I specify which version the spring depends on? The spring's pom is not contains any verison infomation.

Comment: Why would you have 2 version? There is only 1 to be downloaded. This has nothing to do with spring but lack of understanding how maven works.

Comment: @M. Deinum: My code use the httpClient version 5. The spring-web can not depends on version 4 because the method has changed in version 5. The spring-web can not find the method. It will throw an exception when I run my code. So it has to depend on version 4.

Comment: You cannot have different versions. Also if you don't use the HTTP client in spring nothing will break as it is an optional dependency.